# How to get 'Missing XML comment' warnings only for public methods (not protected methods)

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, warnings

I'd like to get a warning for every **public** method without documentation.
The problem: I don't want to write documentation für **protected** methods...

Using 
`#pragma warning disable 1591`
or 'Suppress warnings: 1591' In the project properties, I can only disable warnings for both protected and public methods.

Is there a way to get the warning only for public methods with missing documentation?

Comment: The reason for this warning is that someone else can write a class that inherits your class, and they can then call your protected method. Thus, they need to know the documentation for the method. A protected method is effectively "public" to child classes.